# Как создать синтаксическое дерево для произвольного фрагмента кода на Си?

Tags: c, парсер, дерево

Я студент и в рамках обучения передо мной стоит задача поиска клонов исходного кода в некотором проекте на Си.

Строить дерево для всего проекта не нужно, принимается, что есть некоторые исходные фрагменты, клоны которых и нужно найти, т.е. по сути строить мне нужно только деревья для некоторых произвольных фрагментов исходного кода, а потом их сравнивать, учитывая, что некоторые поддеревья могут отличаться.

Я уже написал в своё время поиск клонов с использованием параметризации некоторых лексем в фрагментах, теперь вот нужно перейти к сравнению этих произвольных фрагментов, как деревьев, т.к. это позволяет найти больше клонов.

Сам я гуглил, но решил, что разумно спросить совета у более опытных людей.
Есть ли такие средства (желательно бесплатные), которые позволят построить синтаксические деревья для произвольных фрагментов исходного кода на Си и которые могут выдать результат хоть в каком-то текстовом формате в стандартный вывод или в файл, чтобы программа, которую я пишу, смогла это считать?

Или какие-нибудь библиотеки для С++, при помощи которых я могу получить представление упомянутых произвольных фрагментов внутри моей программы?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc (основа) + далее по ссылкам, если понадобится. Например, http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/bison_yacc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как правильно подсказывает @PinkTux в комментарии, вам не стоит пытаться писать парсер самостоятельно: это большая и сложная работа, которая не имеет прямого отношения к вашему заданию.

Для разбора языков в синтаксическое дерево традиционно используются утилиты [lex](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex) и [yacc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) (более современные их версии — [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex) и [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)). Вам придётся выучить их форматы, но, поверьте, это пригодится в жизни не раз. Flex и bison бесплатны, развиваются и поддерживаются.

Есть несколько готовых грамматик для языка C, интернет, кажется, считает лучшей эту пару: http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l-2011.html + http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html. Поэтому не стоит изобретать велосипед. Возьмите готовую грамматику, добавьте построение классы для синтаксического дерева, и можно приступать к вашему главному заданию.

[Вам придётся добавить к правилам наподобие `WHILE '(' expression ')' statement` код построения части дерева, например:

```
WHILE '(' expression ')' statement { $$ = new while_statement($3, $5) }
```

что означает «результату разбора выражения (`$$`) присвоить `new while_statement` с параметрами `$3` (третье выражение в списке, `expression`) и `$5` (пятое выражение в списке, `statement`) », но это тривиально.]

Дерзайте! У вас прекрасная задача!